# product gallery attachment url in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gallery

I'm using this snippet to output the product gallery attachments on a custom wordpress template for a woocommerce site. I'm using a lightbox for the popup. But I struggling to get the attachment url, instead it keeps on using the featured image the pop-up.

```
<?php
global $product;
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' );
$url = $thumb['0']; 


echo '<div>';
foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{
echo '<a href="' . $url . '" rel="shadowbox" >' ."<img src=".$image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id, 'large')." style='width:70px; height:70px;' >". '</a>';
 }
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Any ideas on how to target the correct url path for the product gallery images?
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried : $image_link = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'large'); ?

Comment: Hi, I have tried it for the 'a href ' part but it does not output anything. weird, as its using this for the image src reference which does work...

Comment: Have you tried adding global $post; below global $product; ? I think because it's outside of "the loop".

Comment: This is the page in question. http://www.airloom.co.za/product/kelim-bright/ There is a thumbnail gallery on right side, when clicking on it, it brings up the main featured image instead of the gallery image..

Comment: See updated edit on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed `'thumbnail_size'` to `'large'` added `global $post;` and changed `.wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'large').`.

The `$post` will need to be decalered globaly to access it's contents since this is outside "the loop".

**EDIT 2** I've updated the code below so it should link to the image clicked. Removed `$thumb` and `$url` as it's not being used.

```
<?php
global $product;
global $post;

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

echo '<div>';

foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
{
    echo '<a href="' .wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'large'). '" rel="shadowbox" >' ."<img src=".wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'large')." style='width:70px; height:70px;' >". '</a>';
}

echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanx for your help, but that gives me a broken link for the thumbnail now.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
  global $product;
     $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) 
    {
      //Get URL of Gallery Images - default wordpress image sizes
      echo $Original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
      echo $full_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' )[0];
      echo $medium_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'medium' )[0];
      echo $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' )[0];

      //Get URL of Gallery Images - WooCommerce specific image sizes
      echo $shop_thumbnail_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_thumbnail' )[0];
      echo $shop_catalog_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_catalog' )[0];
      echo $shop_single_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'shop_single' )[0];

      //echo Image instead of URL
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'medium');
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_thumbnail');
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_catalog');
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'shop_single');
    }
```